# How to sort and store only the top 3 locations from two .CSV files and then store them into two columns in one .CSV file using Python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Sort the data in the files average2016.csv  and average2017.csv. Store only the top 3 locations from each file. The top 3 locations data will be stored in one file, name it top3.csv. Each column in the top3.csv file will store the results of each year. Thus, the top3.csv file will have the columns 2016 and 2017.

This is a small portion of average2016.csv file
[image: Small portion of average2016]
This is a small portion of average2017.csv file
[image: Small portion of average2017]

I am using Python 3.8 with Pandas

I am not sure how to go about this. I need to sort the data in these files. I need to store only the top 3 locations from each .CSV file. The top 3 locations will be the top 3 averages from the average .CSV files. Then I have to store those top 3 averages from each average file into one file, top3.csv. The new, .CSV file, needs to have two columns, 2016 and 2017.

I was thinking of something along the lines of this for each file:

```
df = pd.read_csv('average2016.csv')

df.nlargest(3, ['SNOW'])
```

Comment: _I am not sure how to go about this._ You're likely going to need to be far more specific than that. Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured it out. You need 2 things, re and name of the file.

```
import re 
year_format = re.compile(r'[0-9]{4}')
result = pd.DataFrame()
for filename in ['average2016.csv', 'average2017.csv']:
    file = pd.read_csv(filename)
    # value_counts() will return a sorted series base on occurance
    # convert to dict and get keys to get the most occured locations 
    all_loc = dict(file['NAME'].value_counts()).keys()
    # delete the above line, and uncomment the following:
    # all_loc = list(dict(file['NAME'].value_counts()).items())
    # all_loc.sort(key=lambda item: item[1], revese=True)
    # all_loc = [item[0] for item in all_loc]
    most_loc = list(all_loc)[:3]
    year = year_format.search(filename).group()
    result[year] = most_loc
result.to_csv('yourfilename.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: I am getting a SyntaxError: invalid syntax on the line: result.append(temp, ignore_index=True)

Comment: i missed a ')' on the previous line, mybad

Comment: Okay that fixed the error but when I executed it, it gave me an empty .CSV file

Comment: mybad, i forgot append is not inplace

Comment: That worked. Is there a way to make each of the 3 results show up on separate lines?

Comment: oh, crap, they got there as a list didn't they. Let me fix that real quick

Comment: Sorry I keep bothering you, that worked but I realized I need them in two columns, one  with a heading of 2016 and one for 2017. Is that possible to do with the code you've sent me?

Comment: Don't worry about it, that can be easily achieved with a small modification, please upvote if you think this is helpful, huge thanks. I'm new to stackoverflow, trying to help out

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much for all of the help! I appreciate it!

Comment: One thing I noticed when I was executing this is that my results keep changing. Is there a fix for that?

Comment: interesting, it shouldn't change at all. value_counts() always sort by occurancse. try to print the value_counts somewhere else to check if it's the code's error or data's error. if code's error, see commented lines

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211399/discussion-between-bridget-and-michael-hsi).